# How to find such $v_j$ and smooth functions $f_i$'s

Tags: analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The following question is from my assignment on smooth maps and I am really at loss of ideas on how should I approach this question:

> Let $F: M \to N$ be a smooth map between manifolds of dimension n. Let $p\in M$ and let ($U, \phi$) and ($V,\psi)$ be the charts containing p and F(p) respectively. The charts ($U, \phi$) and ($ V,\psi$) give ordered bases for $T_P M$ and $T_P N$ respectively. Let A be the $n \times n$ matrix representing dF(p) with respect to these ordered bases. Show that we can find $v_j\in T_P M $, $i\leq j \leq n$ and smooth functions $f_i : N \to \mathbb{R}$, $ 1\leq i \leq n$ such that $A_{ij} = dF_p(v_j)(f_i)$.

I tried to use the information given in question. But the problem is that I am not so good in question involving matrices despite studying Linear Algebra from Hoffman and Kunze.So, I am completely struck on the problem and couldn't even start the problem.

I know that I don't added much as attempt but I am not able to make any progress and that is the reason. Kindly don't vote to close it and kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works if $\dim M\neq\dim N$. Set $m := \dim M$ and $n := \dim N$.

Let $\alpha: \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a smooth map with compact support satisfying the following properties:

$$\mathrm{supp}\,\alpha\subset \psi(V)$$
$$\psi(F(p))\notin \mathrm{supp}(1-\alpha)$$

Define $\partial_j\in T_{\phi(p)}\mathbb R^m$ via $\partial_j f := \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}\right|_{x=\phi(p)}$. Set $v_j := d(\phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}(\partial_j)$.

Analogously, define $\tilde\partial_i\in T_{\psi(F(p))}\mathbb R^n$ via $\tilde\partial_i f := \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^i}\right|_{y=\psi(F(p))}$.

for $w\in\mathbb R^n$, let $w^i$ denote the $i$-th component of $w$. Define $f_i:N\to\mathbb R$ as follows:

$$
f_i(y) := 
\begin{cases}
\alpha(\psi(y))\cdot (\psi(y))^i &, y\in V\\
0 &, y\notin V
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly, $f_i$ is smooth on $V$. On $N\setminus\psi^{-1}(\mathrm{supp}\,\alpha)$, $f_i$ is constantly $0$ and thus smooth. Since these two open sets cover $N$, $f_i$ is smooth.

Let $W := \psi^{-1}\left( \mathbb R^n\setminus\mathrm{supp}(1-\alpha) \right)$. $W$ is an open neighbourhood of $F(p)$. For $y\in W$, $\alpha(\psi(y)) = 1$ and therefore $f_i(y) = (\psi(y))^i$.

For $1\le i\le n$ and $1\le j\le m$:

\begin{align*}
dF_p(v_j)(f_i) &= dF_p\left(d(\phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}(\partial_j)\right)(f_i)\\
&= d(\psi^{-1})_{\psi(F(p))}\left(d(\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}(\partial_j)\right)(f_i)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n A_{kj} d(\psi^{-1})_{\psi(F(p))}(\tilde\partial_k)(f_i)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n A_{kj} \tilde\partial_k (f_i\circ \psi^{-1})\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n A_{kj} \left.\frac{\partial (f_i\circ \psi^{-1})}{\partial y^k}\right|_{y=\psi(F(p))}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n A_{kj} \left.\frac{\partial \left(f_i|_W\circ \psi^{-1}|_{\psi(W)}\right)}{\partial y^k}\right|_{y=\psi(F(p))}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n A_{kj} \left.\frac{\partial (y\mapsto y^i)}{\partial y^k}\right|_{y=\psi(F(p))}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n A_{kj} \delta_{ik}\\
&= A_{ij}
\end{align*}

Comment: How $f_i$ is constantly zero on $N/ \psi^{-1}(supp \alpha)$ and how does these two sets open sets cover N?

Comment: How W must be an open nbd of F(p)?

Comment: Kindly reply if you have some spare time.

Comment: Can you please reply?

Comment: Let $y\in N\setminus\psi^{-1}(\mathrm{supp} \alpha)$. There are two cases. If $y\notin V$, then $f_i(y) = 0$ by the definition of $f_i$. If $y\in V$, then $f_i(y) = 0\cdot \psi(y)^i = 0$ because $\alpha(\psi(y)) = 0$.

Comment: By definition of $\alpha$, $\psi(F(p))\notin \mathrm{supp}(1-\alpha)$, thus $F(p)\in W$. The set $\mathbb R^n\setminus\mathrm{supp}(1-\alpha)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ because supports are closed by definition. Since $\psi:V\to\mathbb R^n$ is continuous, this implies that $W$ is open in $V$. Since $V\subset N$ is open, this means that $W$ is open in $N$.